# Creates a tri-generational family tree (grandfather, mother, child)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I left out the `helper()` function because it is gargantuan and is a problem for another day.

Basically, this program asks for:

- Your name
- Your parents
- Number of siblings
- Marital status
- Number of spouses
- Number of children for each spouse

It then dumps everything into a helper function which draws said family tree to a *.txt* file.

The output is something like this:

> ```
> Grandfather  +  Grandmother
>              |
>              |
> --------------------    
>    |         |          
> Daughter    Son + Daughter in-law
>                 |
>                 |
>       -----------------
>          |         |
>       Grandson Granddaughter
> ```

where the variables and program starts from the *son's* point of view (*his* parents, *his* siblings, *his* children, *his* spouses).

```py
def create_family():
    system("cls")
    main_person = input("\nWho is the main person? He/She should \
    have parents and children of their own: ").title()

    father = input("\nWho is {0}'s father?: ".format(main_person)).title()
    mother = input("\nWho is {0}'s mother?: ".format(main_person)).title()

    x = True #Prevents program from shutting down immediately
    while x is True:
        try:
            children_1 = int(input("\nHow many children do {0} and {1} have together\
?: ".format(father, mother)))
            x = False
        except ValueError:
            print("\n\tPLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER!")          

    if children_1 < 1: #catch impossible answers
        print("They cant have zero children!")
        system("pause")
        return

    list_1 = [main_person,]
    print("\nAlright. Now, please enter their names. Excluding {}!".format(main_person))

    for i in range(children_1 -1): #Gen 2 has been entered
        child_1 = input("\nMay I know their names?: ").title()
        print("Thank you. {} was added to the list of children.".format(child_1))
        list_1.insert(0,child_1)
      #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#print("Debugging check 1: {} and {} have {} children, of which are {}".format(father,mother,children_1,clean_list_1))

system("pause")
system("cls")
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    marriage = input("Is {0} married?(y/n): ".format(main_person)).lower()
    if "yes" in marriage or "y" in marriage:
        family = {} #wife: children, wife: children
        list_2 = []
        list_3 = [] #second wife's children
        list_4 = [] #third wife's children
        list_5 = [] #fourth wife's children
        counter = 0
        wife_counter = 1

        y = True
        while y is True:
            try:
                n_spouses = int(input("\nHow many spouses does {0} have?: ".format(main_person)))
                y = False
            except ValueError:
                print("\n\tPLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER!")

        if n_spouses < 1: #catch impossible statements
            print("You cant have 0 spouses! You said you were married!")      
            system("pause")
            return

        for i in range(n_spouses): #for each wife, repeat if more than one wife.

            if wife_counter == 1:
                suffix = "1st"
            elif wife_counter == 2:
                suffix = "2nd"
            elif wife_counter == 3:
                suffix = "3rd"
            elif wife_counter == 4:
                suffix = "4th"

            spouse_name = input("\n\tWhat is the {0} spouse's name?: ".format(suffix)).title()
            print("\n Thank you. {0} has been added as {1}'s spouse".format(spouse_name, main_person))

            z = True
            while z is True:
                try:
                    children_2 = int(input("\nHow many children do {0} and {1} have?\nEnter 0 if none!: ".format(main_person, spouse_name)))
                    z = False
                except ValueError:
                    print("\n\t PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER")

            if children_2 > 0: #if each wife got children

                for i in range(children_2): #add the children to a list
                    child_2 = input("\nMay I know their names?: ").title()
                    print(child_2, "has been added to {0} and {1}'s family!".format(main_person, spouse_name))

                    if counter == 0: #First wife
                        list_2.append(child_2)
                    elif counter == 1: #Second wife
                        list_3.append(child_2)
                    elif counter == 2: #And so on...
                        list_4.append(child_2)
                    elif counter == 3:
                        list_5.append(child_2)

                if counter == 0: #Associate each wife to her children
                    family[spouse_name] = list_2
                elif counter == 1:
                    family[spouse_name] = list_3
                elif counter == 2:
                    family[spouse_name] = list_4
                elif counter == 3:
                    family[spouse_name] = list_5

                counter += 1 #to associate the first wife with her children, and the second with hers
                wife_counter += 1 #to display correct 1st, 2nd or 3rd!

            else:
                helper(main_person, father, mother, list_1, family = False, wife_name = spouse_name)          

        if children_2 > 0: # cant put it in the loop^
            helper(main_person, father, mother, list_1, family = family, wife_name = spouse_name)

        #print("Debugging check 2: {0} and {1} have {2} children. They are {3}".format(main_person, spouse_name, children_2, ", ".join(list_2)))

    else:
        helper(main_person, father, mother, list_1, family = False, wife_name = False)

create_family()
```

After reading, it seems that the general consensus is to break up that gargantuan `create_family()` function into smaller chunks of code as per the *divide and conquer* strategy. Below is the rewritten version of the above.

```py
def the_children(main_person, children_2, counter, family, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5, spouse_name):

    for i in range(children_2): #add the children to a list
        child_2 = input("\nMay I know their names?: ").title()
        print(child_2, "has been added to {0} and {1}'s family!".format(main_person, spouse_name))

        if counter == 0: #First wife
            list_2.append(child_2)
        elif counter == 1: #Second wife
            list_3.append(child_2)
        elif counter == 2: #And so on...
            list_4.append(child_2)
        elif counter == 3:
            list_5.append(child_2)

    if counter == 0: #Associate each wife to her children
        family[spouse_name] = list_2
    elif counter == 1:
        family[spouse_name] = list_3
    elif counter == 2:
        family[spouse_name] = list_4
    elif counter == 3:
        family[spouse_name] = list_5



def spouses(main_person, n_spouses,father, mother, list_1, wife_counter):
    counter = -1

    family = {} #wife: children, wife: children
    list_2 = []
    list_3 = [] #second wife's children
    list_4 = [] #third wife's children
    list_5 = [] #fourth wife's children

    for i in range(n_spouses): #for each wife, repeat if more than one wife.
        wife_counter += 1 #to display correct 1st, 2nd or 3rd!
        counter += 1 #to associate the first wife with her children, and the second with hers

        if wife_counter == 1:
            suffix = "1st"
        elif wife_counter == 2:
            suffix = "2nd"
        elif wife_counter == 3:
            suffix = "3rd"
        elif wife_counter == 4:
            suffix = "4th"

        spouse_name = input("\n\tWhat is the {0} spouse's name?: ".format(suffix)).title()
        print("\n Thank you. {0} has been added as {1}'s spouse".format(spouse_name, main_person))

        z = True
        while z is True:
            try:
                children_2 = int(input("\nHow many children do {0} and {1} have?\nEnter 0 if none!: ".format(main_person, spouse_name)))
                z = False
            except ValueError:
                print("\n\t PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER")

        if children_2 > 0:
            the_children(main_person, children_2, counter, family, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5, spouse_name)
        else:
            helper(main_person, father, mother, list_1, family = False, wife_name = spouse_name)                        

    helper(main_person, father, mother, list_1, family = family, wife_name = spouse_name)


def married(main_person, father, mother, list_1):    
    system("cls")

    marriage = input("Is {0} married?(y/n): ".format(main_person)).lower()
    if "yes" in marriage or "y" in marriage:

        y = True
        while y is True:
            try:
                n_spouses = int(input("\nHow many spouses does {0} have?: ".format(main_person)))
                y = False
            except ValueError:
                print("\n\tPLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER!")

        if n_spouses < 1: #catch impossible statements
            print("You cant have 0 spouses! You said you were married!")      
            system("pause")
            return

        spouses(main_person, n_spouses, father, mother, list_1, wife_counter = 0)

    else:
        helper(main_person, father, mother, list_1, family = False, wife_name = False)

def create_family():
    system("cls")
    main_person = input("\nWho is the main person? He/She should \
have parents and children of their own.\nEg. Simon, Xavier,\
Stephen, Jaya Mary \n\n\tperson: ").title()

    father = input("\nWho is {0}'s father?: ".format(main_person)).title()
    mother = input("\nWho is {0}'s mother?: ".format(main_person)).title()

    x = True #Prevents program from shutting down immediately
    while x is True:
        try:
            children_1 = int(input("\nHow many children do {0} and {1} have together\
?: ".format(father, mother)))
            x = False
        except ValueError:
            print("\n\tPLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER!")          

    if children_1 < 1: #catch impossible answers (simon exists, they MUST have at least 1 children!)
        print("They cant have zero children!")
        system("pause")
        return


    list_1 = [main_person,]
    print("\nAlright. Now, please enter their names. Excluding {}!".format(main_person))

    for i in range(children_1 -1): #Gen 2 has been entered
        child_1 = input("\nMay I know their names?: ").title()
        print("Thank you. {} was added to the list of children.".format(child_1))
        list_1.insert(0,child_1)

    married(main_person, father, mother, list_1)


create_family()
```

Which of the above two is more readable and recommended? I'm asking this because despite popular opinion, I still find them equally difficult to read and understand. Secondly, if anyone has any ideas to further refine the code, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version is better, but can still be improved. Part of the reason for breaking things into multiple functions, beyond just better organization, is to reduce code duplication, and there's room to do some more in that department.

### Input loops

For example, you have a handful of similar input-entering and -validating loops. These could be abstracted into a generic input method:

```
def int_prompt(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("\n\tPLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER!")
```

You won't need the `x = True; while x` flag if you just directly try to `return`.

### Lists instead of separate vars

Another slightly awkward part is the separate `list_2`, `list_3`, etc., and the `if-elif` chains to deal with them. You could simplify this by using one list of lists, so then you can index into it instead of using `if` statements:

```
def the_children(main_person, children_2, counter, family, lists, spouse_name):

    for i in range(children_2): #add the children to a list
        child_2 = input("\nMay I know their names?: ").title()
        print(child_2, "has been added to {0} and {1}'s family!".format(main_person, spouse_name))

        lists[counter].append(child_2)

    # Associate each wife to her children
    family[spouse_name] = lists[counter]
```

But now it's clear that `the_children()` only ever modifies one of the `lists` per call (`lists[counter]`), so we could rewrite it to only take the relevant list, and forget about `counter`:

```
def the_children(main_person, n_children, family, children_list, spouse_name):

    for _ in range(n_children):
        child = input("\nMay I know their names?: ").title()
        print(child, "has been added to {0} and {1}'s family!".format(main_person, spouse_name))
        children_list.append(child)

    family[spouse_name] = children_list
```

Actually, it looks like `list_2` and co. are only used between `spouses` and `children`. It should be possible then for `spouses` to just pass the `family` dict into `children` to be modified, without any intermediate lists:

```
def the_children(main_person, n_children, family, spouse_name):
    family[spouse_name] = []

    for _ in range(n_children):
        child = input("\nMay I know their names?: ").title()
        print(child, "has been added to {0} and {1}'s family!".format(main_person, spouse_name))
        family[spouse_name].append(child)


def spouses(main_person, n_spouses, father, mother, list_1):
    family = {}

    # wife counter is just 1 .. n_spouses
    for wife_counter in range(1, n_spouses + 1):
        suffix = get_suffix(wife_counter)

        spouse_name = input("\n\tWhat is the {0} spouse's name?; ".format(suffix)).title()
        print("\n Thank you. {0} has been added as {1}'s spouse".format(spouse_name, main_person))

        n_children = int_prompt("\nHow many children do {0} and {1} have?\nEnter 0 if none!; ".format(main_person, spouse_name))

        if n_children > 0:
            the_children(main_person, n_children, family, spouse_name)
        else:
            helper(main_person, father, mother, list_1, family=False, wife_name=spouse_name)

    helper(main_person, father, mother, list_1, family=family, wife_name=spouse_name)
```

### Data model

Finally, as I'm sure you realize, genealogy can get pretty tangled. Your application may scale better (to more generations, etc.) if you had a more distinctly defined data model.

Essentially this is a directed graph. Son to Grandfather is a Parent edge, Grandfather and Grandmother have a bidirectional Marriage edge, and so on. You could look at graph libraries like NetworkX -- although this is likely (definitely ;) overengineering if you'll only ever have three generations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you expand on what you mean by _defined data model_ ?

Comment: @AstralWolf Sure, that was vague, sorry. I meant defining a specific data structure to represent a `Family` and/or `Person`, instead of having separate strings and lists like `main_person`, `father`, `list_1`, etc., may be easier to pass around through your functions, and easier to expand -- say if you wanted to add birth dates for each person, or marriage dates, or something. Right now things are more ad hoc, which is fine at this scale but could complicate the process of adding more features (more generations, etc.) -- does that help?

Comment: Yes, i see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

## Readability

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends to limit the line length under 80 characters. It improves readability. It also has the advantage that here, on the Stack Exchange network, you don't need the horizontal scrollbar.

You sometimes get this done using explicit line continuation (`\`); for instance in:

```
    main_person = input("\nWho is the main person? He/She should \
have parents and children of their own.\nEg. Simon, Xavier,\
Stephen, Jaya Mary \n\n\tperson: ").title()
```

First of, the indentation feels very weird this way. You can use string continuation instead of line continuation to fix that:

```
    main_person = input(
        "\nWho is the main person? He/She should "\
        "have parents and children of their own.\n"\
        "Eg. Simon, Xavier, Stephen, Jaya Mary \n\n"\
        "\tperson: ").title()
```

You can also get rid of  the `\` at the end of lines since there is an implicit continuation when you have an expression inside parenthesis.

## `os.system`: Portability & User Experience

When I run your program on my system, I first get an error message:

```
$ python codereview.py 
sh: cls : commande introuvable

Who is the main person? He/She should have parents and children of their own.
...
```

This is because the `cls` system command only works on windows. For this one you can easily check on which platform you are and use the `cls` command on windows and `clear` otherwise. For instance:

```
import os

def clear():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
```

And you can then use `clear()` instead of `system('cls')`.

For `system('pause')` the easiest and closest thing to do would be to `input('Press the Enter key to continue...')` (instead of *any* key) without assigning its result to a variable. This is not exactly the same and we could achieve a better result using `select` and directly reading from `sys.stdin` but…

…Do you really need to break the flow that way? Your program is really slow since it spend most of its time waiting for user input. Why add yet another waiting command? Plus everything will be on the screen (I assume `helper` will print the trees), won't it? How else would one be able to get the trees for all the spouses and children? I don't know if `helper` clear the screen too, but it would impair the usability of the program if it did. Anyway, having the screen wiped out with no apparent reason like that sounds terrible (as regard to UX) to me.

I don't know if I’m clear enough, but the point is: I don't think that using either `system('cls')` or `system('pause']` is a good idea for your users experience.

One other thing to note is, when asking for the names of the children: the phrasing is ambiguous and I would be tempted to input all of them at once if I didn't read the code beforehand.

## On building lists out of `for` and `append`

When `append`ing elements to a list in a `for` loop to build them (such as in `create_family`), it is considered best practices to use a list-comprehension instead. It both is considered more readable and has better performances. So instead of¹

```
for i in range(children_1 -1): #Gen 2 has been entered
    child_1 = input("\nMay I know their names?: ").title()
    print("Thank you. {} was added to the list of children.".format(child_1))
    list_1.insert(0,child_1)
```

consider using

```
list_1 = [input("\nMay I know their names?: ").title() for _ in range(children_1 - 1)]
list_1.append(main_person) # compensate for the missing initialization
```

If you really want to echo the name entered, you can define your own function and use it:

```
def echo_input(message, format_msg=None):
    data = input(message).title()
    if format_msg is not None:
        print(format_msg.format(data))
    else:
        print(data)
    return data

list_1 = [echo_input(
        "\nMay I know their names?: ",
        "Thank you. {} was added to the list of children.")
    for _ in range(children_1 - 1)]
list_1.append(main_person)
```

Also note the use of `_` instead of a named variable when the variable will not be used.

## On leaving code at the top-level of the file

Even if not much, the last line (`create_family()`) should not be left at the to of the file. It is good practice to put it under an `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause, as so

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_family()
```

The rationale being that when importing your file (for instance in an interactive session, for testing purposes, say because you splitted your code in more, tinyer functions, as suggested by @BenC), the script doesn't start it's execution, leaving you a clean state and the ability to choose what you want to do. On the other hand, when starting the script from the command line, it will pass the `if` successfully and start the execution.

---

¹ Ok, it's not `append` here but the speech remains valid. Especially since using `insert(0, <something>)` has to move the tail of the list in memory.

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented all your ideas save for the list comprehension as I couldn't really grasp it. Yes, the program does clear the screen and pause so that the user can read the last message at certain intervals. Mainly at the middle and at the end. Helper does also clear the screen, types the output onto the screen, and then saves the output in a _.txt_ file for future use. I feel it gives the program a cleaner look.

Comment: @AstralWolf You can read about list comprehensions [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).